# Maximum Numbers in java

Tags: java, algorithm

Maximum number

We are given a 4 digit number using digits 1 to 9. What is the maximum 3 digit number that we can make by removing one digit from the given integer.
Input Format :
A 4 digit number
Output Format :
A 3 digit number
Sample Input :
5438
Sample Output :
548
Explanation :

1. If we remove 5, the new number is 438.
2. If we remove 4, the new number is 538.
3. If we remove 3, the new number is 548.
4. If we remove 8, the new number is 543.
   Out of the 4 cases removing 3 gives us the maximum 3 digit number i.e 548

Comment: can you show your code

Comment: i'm not able to solve it

Comment: How might you solve it with pencil+paper? Think through how you could approach it by hand, without computers. Once you have a solution idea that works (this will be your algorithm), you can get a computer involved.

Comment: @DibenduGhosh Start learning loop basics.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of this problem, you will be replacing each index location of the input number in a loop and a max variable that tests the new number each time a number is taken away. There will be 4 iterations and everything can be solved within the loop.

Since this looks like a school assignment why don't we start with pseudocode..

```
'
- Declare max as 0, and newNumber
- Declare and ask for inputValue to initialize
- Start a loop for input values length
- Initialize newNumber without the index of inputValue using the loop iteration value
- Initialize max with newNumber if newNumber is greater
- (loop repeats)
- Print out max
'
```

If you simply your steps, it may make it easier to solve. I am a student as well, and this assignment looks fun. Good Luck!

-Blaze

Answer (score 1):

The question is whether we need to find the most optimal algorithm or brute force is enough.

1. in case of brute force removing digit from `k` position (from the right) actually means performing following transformation with `num`: `num % (10^k) + num / (10^(k+1)) * (10^k)`, examples for 5438:

- `k = 0`: `5438 % 1 + 5438 / 10 * 1 = 0 + 543 = 543`
- `k = 1`: `5438 % 10 + 5438 / 100 * 10 = 8 + 540 = 548`
- `k = 2`: `5438 % 100 + 5438 / 1000 * 100 = 38 + 500 = 538`
- `k = 3`: `5438 % 1000 + 5438 / 10000 * 1000 = 438 + 0 = 438`

and the corresponding code is:

```java
    public static int maxNum(int num) {
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < num; i *= 10) {
            max = Math.max(max, num % i + num / (i * 10) * i);
        }
        return max;
    }
```

2. can we find the digit to remove using "more intellectual" way? Let our number is A<sub>n</sub>A<sub>1</sub>...A<sub>k+1</sub>A<sub>k</sub>A<sub>k-1</sub>...A<sub>0</sub> and `F(k): N -> M` is "remove k<sup>th</sup> digit operation" operation, then `F(k+1) - F(k)` = A<sub>k</sub>A<sub>k-1</sub>...A<sub>0</sub> - A<sub>k+1</sub>A<sub>k-1</sub>...A<sub>0</sub> = 10<sup>k-1</sup>(A<sub>k</sub> - A<sub>k+1</sub>), so, we prefer to remove A<sub>k+1</sub> if A<sub>k+1</sub> < A<sub>k</sub>, i.e. it is the last digit in the first monotonic non-increasing sequence, and the code is:

```java
    public static int maxNum(int num) {
        int maxPow = 1;
        while (maxPow < num) {
            maxPow *= 10;
        }
        for (int i = maxPow / 10; i >= 10; i /= 10) {
            int digit = num / i % 10;
            int right = num / (i / 10) % 10;
            if (digit < right) {
                return num % i + num / (i * 10) * i;
            }
        }
        return num / 10;
    }
```